# PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint during SQL Insert

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

Am using JDK 14, PostgreSQL, standard JDBC to create a sample Spring Boot 2.3 Microservice.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.fourteen</groupId>
    <artifactId>fourteen</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fourteen</name>
    <description>JDK 14 Demo</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <release>14</release>
                    <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                    <parameters>true</parameters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

Java source:

```
package com.fourteen;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.GeneratedKeyHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FourteenApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FourteenApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Component
class Runner {

    private final PeopleService peopleService;

    Runner(PeopleService peopleService) {
        this.peopleService = peopleService;
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void exercise() throws Exception {
        Person elizabeth = this.peopleService.create("Elizabeth", EmotionalState.SAD);
        System.out.println(elizabeth);
    }
}

record Person(int id, String name, int emotionalState) {
}

@Service
class PeopleService {

    private final JdbcTemplate template;

    private final String findByIdSql =
        """
         SELECT * FROM PEOPLE
         WHERE ID = ?       
        """;

    private final String insertSql =
        """
         INSERT INTO PEOPLE(name, emotional_state) 
         values (?, ?);
        """;

    PeopleService(JdbcTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    private final RowMapper<Person> personRowMapper =
            (rs, rowNum) -> new Person(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getInt("emotional_state"));

    public Person create(String name, EmotionalState state) throws IllegalAccessException {
        var index = switch(state) {
            case SAD -> -1;
            case NEUTRAL -> 0;
            case HAPPY -> 1;
        };

        var declaredParams = List.of(new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR, "name"),
                                     new SqlParameter(Types.INTEGER, "emotional_state"));

        var pscf = new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(this.insertSql, declaredParams) {
            {
                setReturnGeneratedKeys(true);
                setGeneratedKeysColumnNames("id");
            }
        };

        var psc = pscf.newPreparedStatementCreator(List.of(name, index));
        var kh = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        this.template.update(psc, kh);

        if (kh.getKey() instanceof Integer id) {
            return findById(id);
        }
        throw new IllegalAccessException("We couldn't create the " + Person.class.getName() + "!");
    }

    public Person findById(Integer id) {
        return this.template.queryForObject(this.findByIdSql, new Object[] {id}, this.personRowMapper);
    }
}

enum EmotionalState {
    SAD, HAPPY, NEUTRAL
}
```

---

src/main/application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/orders
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=
```

---

DDL:

```
create table people(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR, emotional_state INTEGER);
```

---

Describe people table:

```
\d people
```

Query results:

```
                        Table "public.people"
     Column      |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id              | integer           |           | not null | 
 name            | character varying |           |          | 
 emotional_state | integer           |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "people_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

---

When I run the Spring Application via IntelliJ IDEA:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.0.RELEASE)

2020-05-21 09:32:19.174  INFO 28160 --- [           main] com.fourteen.FourteenApplication         : Starting FourteenApplication on DevBox.local with PID 28160 (/Users/pnwlover/code/fourteen/target/classes started by pnwlover in /Users/pnwlover/code/fourteen)
2020-05-21 09:32:19.175  INFO 28160 --- [           main] com.fourteen.FourteenApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-21 09:32:19.723  INFO 28160 --- [           main] com.fourteen.FourteenApplication         : Started FourteenApplication in 0.768 seconds (JVM running for 1.338)
2020-05-21 09:32:19.728  INFO 28160 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-21 09:32:19.997  INFO 28160 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-05-21 09:32:20.090 ERROR 28160 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [           INSERT INTO PEOPLE(name, emotional_state)
            values (?, ?);
]; ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, Elizabeth, -1).; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, Elizabeth, -1).
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:247) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) 
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, Elizabeth, -1).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2533) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2268) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:313) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12

2020-05-21 09:32:20.092  INFO 28160 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-05-21 09:32:20.096  INFO 28160 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

What is it failing to insert a new record?

Comment: Your `id` column should be marked as `generated always as identity` (or as of `serial` type if your using an older version of postgresql).

Comment: Thank you @Marth! This worked (after dropping my people table and then recreating with this: ```create table people(id integer generated always as identity, name varchar, emotional_state integer);```